# Prototyping disposable protective tong sleeves - materials?

Tags: materials

I am interested in, perhaps, going in the direction of bio-plastics. However there might be some other options I haven't yet thought of, so that's the reason I'm opening this dialogue.

[image: Conceptual prototype made from polyethylene and scotch tape]

Before securing a manufacturer, I want to know what limitations, or options, I may have with regard to food safety, durability of product, look and feel of said materials, and implementation. Some compostable materials might not meet certain food-safety needs, perhaps exposure to acids or heat might result in types of unwanted degradation.

[image: 3D model]

I am, basically, asking to collectively weigh the pros and cons of each material (e.g. Bio polyethylene, corn plastics) against the elements. 
Which would be the absolute best material to use? Not only for functionality, but for the sake of being eco friendly also.

Comment: Hi Joseph, our site has a very strictly specified scope. Basically, you can only ask about a subset of problems which *cooks* face in their daily work. So your question is off topic. Luckily, we are part of a larger network of Q&A sites on different topics, and we also have a site for engineering. I migrated your question to it, since I think it does take your type of question.

Comment: Define your constraints such as temperature : are these for salads or for cooking in the frying pan different materials different characteristics.

Comment: if i could push out the product under pretense of light duty prep, great. But to have a version meant to withstand oil splatter, perhaps the kind from handling raw meats or fish, upon searing.  This temperature range might well cap out at 572 f just to be safe. Submerged in boiling bone broths might be another application.